# How to execute a crontab (OS X 10.9) when mac is turned on again

Tags: cron

I was wondering how I could execute a **crontab** which usually occurs when Mac is turned off (not just asleep). As for documentation, OS X skips crontabs if the machine is off. Is there a way to have crontabs to be executed once mac turns on again?

Thank you.

Comment: put the scripts into whatever osx's equivalent of inittab is, into the run-on-startup section(s).

Comment: No unluckily they don't.

Answer (score 6):

You can use: `@reboot`

```
 @reboot /path/to/script
```

**Source**
[Apple's Crontab Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab)

Comment: With 10.14.6  this gives an "Operation not permitted" error.

Comment: Sorry to hear! I haven't checked in a while, and I'm sorry this 7 year old post couldn't help. I will try to edit if I find a way.

Comment: For unknown reason a reboot fixed this: Then a UI window pops up which asks to allow or deny the modification of crontab. No clue why it didn't worked before the reboot.